# How to set magic pointer values on arbitrary pointer types

Tags: c++, pointers, lifetime

I have an application in which I've experienced some rare segmentation faults due to nullptr dereferences. The pointer values in the application follow a pretty standard life cycle:

1. I initialize them to nullptr.
2. They get set to a value at some point early on when information becomes available to set them to a constructed instance.
3. They then get used for a time.
4. They finally get freed, after which point I set them to null.

When I do post mortem analysis on a core, it would be helpful to know whether the pointer had a nullptr value because it was just uninitialized but not set to an actual instance (i.e., between steps 1 and 2 above) or because it had been previously freed (after step 4 above). To help with this analysis, I would like to use magic pointer values for the initialization and post-free'ing of the objects. I have in mind hexspeak values such as `0xCAFEBABE` and `0xDEADBEEF` for steps 1 and 4, respectively.

I have multiple types of pointers that I would like to use for this. I find that for any given type, I can initialize it using an explicit cast. Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(int a) : _a{a} {};
    int _a;
};

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A *a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(0xCAFEBABE);
    cout << a->_a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This does what I want: when I run this, it crashes and when I print the value of `a` in the debugger it prints `0x00000000cafebabe`.

However, specifying the reinterpret_cast for each pointer type, once for each initialization and once after each destruction, will get tedious. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

---

**Update**

A couple people added comments recommending that I manage these pointers with smart pointers. I appreciate the intention of this feedback, but that advice does not apply to this situation because this is not a bug with managing the lifetime of these objects. In general, the instances of my classes in this application are managed by smart pointers. In the particular case of this crash the pointers are for OpenSSL objects which are constructed with SSL_new and freed with SSL_free. But that's beside the point: they are correctly constructed when a connection is created and correctly freed when the connection goes away. The instances should not exist outside of that timeframe. The bug presents itself when a part of my application attempts a write using one of these non-live instances. In order to help track this down, I'd like to know whether the write happened on an object before the connection was set up or after the connection went away. That's where the magic pointer values come in.

Comment: If you need this I'm guessing you haven't embraced containers and smart pointers to the level you *should* have and are still doing manual memory management (why?)..

Comment: You could make your own smart-ish pointer type that does this initialization and provides `operator*` and `operator->` but that still doesn't solve the problem: there _will be a period of time_ that the pointer is not initialized and _nothing you do will change that._ Even in your example, there is a period of time where `a` is not initialized: in between allocation of the storage for `a` and when the assignment happens.

Comment: And, just to reiterate that point, just for the heck of it I counted the number of lines in one of my libraries. More than 250k lines of code, and I do not believe that it has a single `new` or `delete` in it.

Comment: If you really really insist on using raw pointers and `reinterpret_cast` is tedious, just write a function for it. You may also want to look at _pointer tagging_ techniques (instead of using some magic numbers). Typically, you can employ few most significant bits or even few least significant bits if a pointer is used for dynamic allocations.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That very much depend on the application area. I believe most libraries can and should be written this way, but not all can.

Comment: the description in the update sounds likea  perfect use case for `unique_ptr` with custom deleter

Comment: You could wrap your raw pointers in a class that sets the representation initially, and in other respects allows assignment, dereference etc. like a raw pointer:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an use a function template to remove the tedium a bit.

```
template <typename Object>
Object* get_pointer()
{
   return reinterpret_cast<Object*>(0xCAFEBABE);
}

template <typename Object>
Object* get_pointer(Object* /*unused*/)
{
   return get_pointer<Object>();
}
```

and use it as:

```
A* a = get_pointer(a);
```

or

```
A* a = get_pointer<A>();
```

Comment: Isn't `A* a = get_pointer(a);` technically UB as it reads an uninitialized variable? The value is not used, but if the read is not optimized away, could this not trigger a hardware trap on some platforms?

Comment: @cdhowie not per [`[basic.life]/7`](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-7.sentence-3): "[Before] the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated [...] any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used [...] using the properties of the glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined."

Comment: Note though: crafting a pointer value from an arbitrary intefger is [_implementation-dependant_](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.safety#4).

Comment: @YSC Is not making a copy of the object to pass it as an argument "depending on its value," even if the callee ignores it? Is there some verbiage in the specification that declares that a function ignoring an argument means the caller does not "use" any object that would be copied to create the argument?